# Searching for consecutive values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

What's the best way to search for consecutive values in an array?

For example, searching for `array('a', 'b')` in `array('x', 'a', 'b', 'c')` would yield `1`, because the values first appear consecutively at that index.

Comment: are there duplicate values or not?

Comment: there are no duplicate values in either array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but something like this should do:

```
function consecutive_values(array $needle, array $haystack) {
    $i_max = count($haystack)-count($needle);
    $j_max = count($needle);
    for($i=0; $i<$i_max; ++$i) {
        $match = true;
        for($j=0; $j<$j_max; ++$j) {
            if($needle[$j]!=$haystack[$i+$j]) {
                $match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($match) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This is better than my approach. Tested. Works.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably sub-optimal but is fairly concise:

```
$needle = array('a', 'b');
$haystack = array('x', 'a', 'b', 'c');

function searchInArray($haystack, $needle)
{
    $keys = array_search($haystack, $needle[0]);

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $endPos = $key + count($needle);   
        for ($i=1; $i<$count($needle); $i++) {
            if ($needle[$i] == $haystack[$key + $i]) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you're returning upon the first match...they *all* need to match.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're asking for, it's somewhat specific as all arrays must be non-keyed, and have unique values.

Additionally, in this version the arrays can only contain integer or string values. If you need any NULL, object, float and arrays as well, a part of it needs to be changed from the `array_flip()` + `isset()` to `array_search()`.

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/0LVEkIwV)  / [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1018156)

The relevant part is to compare a slice of the array you search in (here `$in`) with the array you search for (here `$for`):

```
array_slice($in, $pos, $len) === $for
```

`$pos` has been looked up earlier for the first value of `$for`, `$len` is `count($for)`.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code within your answer (in addition to the link to a demo).